# $router.push() not a function error using Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

After a new project is created, I'd like to route the user to another page so they can add more information to the project.

**This is working:**

```
createProject() {
      ProjectService.createProject(this.project)
        .then(response => {
          this.$router.push({
            name: "project-update",
            params: { id: response.data.data.id }
          });
        })
}
```

**I'd like to use vuex to handle all this, but this is not working.**

```
createProject() {
  this.$store
    .dispatch("project/postProject", this.project)
    .then(response => {
      this.$router.push({
        name: "project-update",
        params: { id: response.data.data.id }
      });
    })
    .catch(() => {});
}
```

The error I'm getting is: `"state.projects.push is not a function"`

**This is my postProject action in Vuex:**

```
  postProject({ commit, dispatch }, project) {
    return ProjectService.createProject(project)
      .then(() => {
        commit('ADD_PROJECT', project);
        const notification = {
          type: 'success',
          message: 'Your project has been created!'
        };
        dispatch('notification/add', notification, { root: true });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const notification = {
          type: 'error',
          message: 'There was a problem creating your project: ' + error.message
        };
        dispatch('notification/add', notification, { root: true });
        throw error;
      });
  }
```

Looks like the context of 'this' is not reaching the router or the push function therein. How can I access the router and route to that next page?

Comment: Can you add your code of dispatched action and mutation.

Comment: The action and dispatch are working fine, the data is successfully stored in the database and state, only the router is not working.

Comment: you need to include the router module into that vuex module and use `router.push()`

Comment: then how do you get this error state.projects.push is not a function? Just try commenting router.push line and check it its still throwing this error.

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw How do I add the router module? Should I simply place what I have here into the action, or do I have to include something?

Comment: @connorcode, please check my answer. I have included as to how to include router module into your vuex module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is import your router module into your vuex module like so:

```
import {router} from "../main.js"
// or
import router from '../router'

export default {
  actions: {
    createProject () {
      this.$store
        .dispatch("project/postProject", this.project)
        .then(response => {
          router.push({
            name: "project-update",
            params: { id: response.data.data.id }
          })
        })
        .catch(() => { })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your new createProject method ? if you still used `this.$router`, kindly changed it into just `router` only

Comment: I deleted my latest comment once I noticed that. Changed my code to reflect yours and I'm still getting the "state.projects.push is not a function" error

Comment: Tried both import variations

Comment: the router part is done. Next thing is your `postProject` which seems to have a wrong implementation. Can you show your `postProject` method ?

Comment: Most probably your state variable `projects` is an object and not an array. You should check that first by doing console of typeOf of your variable `state.projects`.

Comment: Projects is an array, I edited the question above adding the vuex postProject method.

Comment: I relocated the router code from the component to the vuex action and now it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue but I solved by doing this:

```
this.$router.replace("/");
```

Having issue in vuex and nuxt store by using this : `this.$router.push("/");`